# kubelet fails the running pods even image is present at worker

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Could you guys please help with a confusion of image pull in k8s?

1. **imagePullPolicy: Always => is set in deployment**
2. **image with tag is deployed => nexus.example.com/abc-image:**
3. **deployment is running with >1 replicas, lets assume 4** K8s architecture has 10 worker nodes in cluster which can run above
   deployment, **k8s version: 1.17**

The deployment/pods are running perfectly fine. What if the image is deleted from the nexus storage? Would it impact the running pods on worker? Would the running pods be failed because of *ImagePullBackOff* as nexus doesn't have that manifest anymore?
I am asking this because logs says so. I always thought running pods wouldn't fail until local image on worker is deleted and pods/container gets restarted.

```
Apr 14 18:25:34 npl9app17 kubelet[207293]: E0414 18:25:34.142584  207293 remote_image.go:113] PullImage "nexus.example.com/abc-web-service-prod:5.15_130" from image service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for nexus.example.com/abc-web-service-prod:5.15_130 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Apr 14 18:25:34 npl9app17 kubelet[207293]: E0414 18:25:34.142698  207293 kuberuntime_manager.go:803] container start failed: ErrImagePull: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for nexus.example.com/abc-web-service-prod:5.15_130 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Apr 14 18:25:34 npl9app17 kubelet[207293]: E0414 18:25:34.142750  207293 pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod 022c4091-f8ce-4704-aa0c-1c36d70d63d0 ("abc-web-service-c49b95497-5sclr_99-content(022c4091-f8ce-4704-aa0c-1c36d70d63d0)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "abc-web-service" with ErrImagePull: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for nexus.example.com/abc-web-service-prod:5.15_130 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown"
Apr 14 18:25:52 npl9app17 kubelet[207293]: E0414 18:25:52.406219  207293 remote_image.go:113] PullImage "nexus.example.com/abc-web-service-prod:5.15_130" from image service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for nexus.example.com/abc-web-service-prod:5.15_130 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Apr 14 18:25:52 npl9app17 kubelet[207293]: E0414 18:25:52.406395  207293 kuberuntime_manager.go:803] container start failed: ErrImagePull: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for nexus.example.com/abc-web-service-prod:5.15_130 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Apr 14 18:25:52 npl9app17 kubelet[207293]: E0414 18:25:52.406440  207293 pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod 022c4091-f8ce-4704-aa0c-1c36d70d63d0 ("abc-web-service-c49b95497-5sclr_99-content(022c4091-f8ce-4704-aa0c-1c36d70d63d0)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "abc-web-service" with ErrImagePull: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for nexus.example.com/abc-web-service-prod:5.15_130 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown"
```

Comment: Refer to this [documentation](https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-errimagepull-and-imagepullbackoff/) for more information on errimagePull or imagepullbackoff error and their resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

My expectation would match yours.  If the image is deleted on the upstream repository...

**Running pods** wouldn't be affected.

**With `imagePullPolicy: Always`**, any new pods will fail with ImagePullBackOff state.

**With `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`**, any new pods that happen to get created on nodes that already have the image will succeed, and on nodes that don't have them image they will fail.

Note that in various cases pods can be created or deleted outside your immediate control.  If a node is low on some resource, pods that are using more than their resource requests can get evicted; if you have the cluster autoscaler in use, it can terminate pods to free up a node to scale in the cluster; if you have a HorizontalPodAutoscaler configured, it can create and delete pods in response to load.  One of these factors could cause the behavior you're seeing where a new pod is created (and failing to pull) without you taking explicit action.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for you explanation. I do agree with what you said.
Unfortunately, I have this behaviour in my cluster and trying to understand/digest the same. The nodes I've checked does have that image:tag locally still there are those messages in /var/log/messages which I've attached in the question.